# Failing redis.call

Tags: redis, lua

Under which circumstances a `redis.call(command, ...args)` invocation can fail if both `command`is valid and `args` are valid arguments to `command`?

Comment: What is the error code/message?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. This is a generic question. I have no error code/message